# To ignore some pkgs upon release by bloom

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found at [a comment on github](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/1197#issuecomment-20431599) there's a way to ignore certain packages when I release a <s>metapkg</s> repository How exactly is it done?

Suppose in `package` foo with a `tag` bar, create `bar.ignored` on the home directory of foo? And inside of bar.ignore listed are the names of packages that I don't to release like the following?:

```
pkg-foo-a
pkg-foo-b
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66545/to-ignore-some-pkgs-upon-release-by-bloom/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-07-03**:
was it not `bar.ignored` ? (instead of `bar.ignore`)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-03**:
Thanks, now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has nothing to do with metapackages.

When releasing a repository, which contains one or more packages which may or may not be metapackages, you can create a file in the master branch which starts with the track name and has the extension `.ignored`. So if you are running the track `hydro`, then any packages (separated by whitespace) in the `hydro.ignored` file in the master branch will be ignored.

When being ignored a package will not have release branches or debian branches generated and it will not be included in the automatically generated diff nor the pull request.

The explicitly ignored packages will be noted in the README.md summary on the master branch of the repository.

Like this:

https://github.com/wjwwood/roscpp_core-release#roscpp_core---0315-5

---

Edit by @130s
The link to wjwwood/roscpp_core-release above no longer exists. [This in ros-gbp/ros_comm-release](https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/blob/5216c4eac74c16709cb74d075fc6bb87b87553f8/kinetic.ignored) might be another good example.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-03**:
Just to make sure, is `master` branch replaced (eg. with the default branch on my github repo) when no `master` branch exists?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-03**:
No... this is not your upstream repository. This is the release repository. Bloom places all of its configurations on the master branch. There is no way to change this.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-03**:
I see. One more thing; Are multiple packages separated by whitespace? In your example they look 1 pkg per line

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-03**:
Line endings are whitespace.

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2016-09-15**:
William's link no-longer works, so here is another example:

https://github.com/dillenberger/pepperl_fuchs

https://github.com/dillenberger/pepperl_fuchs-release